# How to convert 8 figures grid into easting and northing coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, convert

I am using QGIS 3.10.3. I have an excel file containing some coordinates that looks like 8 figure grid. I would like to compare these coordinates with the start and end of the roads layer (Easting, Northing) in QGIS. How can I convert these coordinate into Easting and Northing coordinates?[image]

Comment: Where should these coordinates be situated?

Comment: It located in Cumbria, UK. The tiles are NY= 35 , DS=34 and NX=25.

Comment: I think these are British National Grid values. NY gives you the first digit of the full 6 figure eastings and northings. I don't know these 4 figure values are missing the 1st,2nd or the 1st,6th digits. When I tried them in [here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-os-gridref.html), it assumed 1st,6th were missing.